# nameOf operator and nameOf expression

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

In the article  [What's New in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6) is the section The nameof expression. In this section first sentence is the link to the article [nameof operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). In the second article is the link to the article [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#nameof-expressions) in which is the section Nameof expressions. I clearly understood what nameof operator produce from the obtained parameter, but the relation between nameof operator, nameof expression and nameof_expression is confused. In the article Expressions the first sentence is the description - An expression is a sequence of operators and operands. According it I understand that the code part in which nameof operator obtains a symbol and provides the name of this symbol is nameof expresion. Is it correct or I misunderstood something? What is the role is of nameof_expression?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The nameof expression is what the compiler understands, the nameof operator is what you as a developer use. Can you try to read your question again and maybe rephrase?

Comment: In `1 + 2`, `+` is the addition operator and `1 + 2` is an addition expression. Same with `nameof` -- `nameof(Int32)` is an expression (of type `string`), using the `nameof` operator. In practice and informally these terms will get used interchangeably if you're not actually dealing with the formal grammar, so don't expect every instance to get it just right.

Comment: nameof is an operator.  In can be used in an expression without any additional operators and operands.  Not unlike the way the new operator works.

Comment: `nameof_expression` defines how you write code using the nameof operator (the expression).

Comment: nameof_expression in the mentioned Expressions article is used in antlr (ANother Tool for Language Recognition) window. I suppose that it is used to expose in more detail nameOf expression, but as I haven't knowledge of antlr it isn't very useful for me.